# Javascript to auto play youtube video?

Tags: javascript, youtube, view, embed

I know that embed code can autoplay but youtube will not calculate these views.
However I search for javascript that automatically play the video after the visitor stay for XX seconds in site.
i.e: I want to Auto Play Youtube Embedded Video without editing the embedding code.
Can that be?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply add a setTimeout function which track the time after the page is loaded and play the video after it :

```
 var time = 3000 //the time in milliseconds 

 document.querySelector('body').onload = function(){

    setTimeout(function(){

        //The code that will run the video

    },time);

 }
```